# Pull page down refresh triggering even when I scroll down the feed

Tags: bug, android-app

Page trying to refresh everytime I try to scroll down the feed

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Huawei
- Device Model: Nexus 6P
- OS Version: 7.0 (3254009)